# WP changing the colour of menu items

Tags: wordpress, menu, hover

I would like to change the font colour of the menu items to #84912C on the website http://www.taranoone.ie when:

a) On the current page
b) On hover

Iv tried doing it and while I have changed the over all colour of the menu, I think I might be having problems of specificity.

Thanks

Comment: post your code , what you have used .

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active { 
    color: #84912C;
}
```

and

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover { 
    color: #84912C;
}
```